# Prove FTC using limit of summation

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

It is not hard to show

$$\int_a^bx^2\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(a+(b-a)\frac kn\right)^2\right]=\frac{b^3}{3}-\frac{a^3}{3}.$$

With some effort one can also show

$$\int_a^b\cos{x}\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\cos\left(a+(b-a)\frac kn\right)\right]=\sin b-\sin a,$$

and even

$$\int_a^b e^x\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ne^{a+(b-a)\frac kn}\right]=e^b-e^a.$$

---

So my question is this.  Is there a 'general summation formula' to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus this way?  In other words, prove

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(a+(b-a)\frac kn\right)\right]=F(b)-F(a),$$

where $F'(x)=f(x)$?

Comment: Can i ask a question ? what about Reimann definite integration theorem ?

Comment: @Cardinal, What exactly is this theorem?  Are you referring to the FTC?  Or the definition of the Riemann integral?  I don't think either applies to my question.  I am asking for a summation technique!

Comment: Do you mean that in those special cases you can evaluate the sum explicitly, and you're asking if the sum can (in some sense) be evaluated explicitly in the general case?

Comment: A general summation which is  directly proceed to F(a) and F(b) ?

Comment: @littleO The sums I mention here can indeed be evaluated explicitly.  The first example being the easiest of course.  So yes I am asking if the sum can be evaluated explicitly in the general case.

Comment: if we break the function to these elementary functions (low effort sums) , can we expect anything ?

Comment: @Cardinal "A general summation which is directly proceed to F(a) and F(b) ?" Yes.  "if we break to these elementary , can we expect anything ?"  I expect so.  The three cases I give as examples can be evaluated directly.

Comment: i think for polynomials we can use multinomial theorem in complex algebraic expressions, in case of trigonometric we use exponential and third-like equations and ... , am I right ?

Comment: I think if we find a solution for hypergeometric functions, then we can cover many complex expressions !

Comment: @Cardinal, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html

Comment: A way to write f(a+b) in terms of f(a) and f(b) would be a good place to start.

Comment: I don't think you can evaluate the sum explicitly (in the general case), but you can make the approximation that $f(x_k) \Delta x \approx F(x_{k+1}) - F(x_k)$, and the sum $\sum_k F(x_{k+1}) - F(x_k)$ can be evaluated because it telescopes.  You could keep track of error terms and prove the total error is small (which would require some mild regularity assumptions on $f$).  Intuitively, $f(x_k) \Delta x \approx F(x_{k+1}) - F(x_k)$, and the error is small even when compared with $\Delta x = (b - a)/n$.  So adding up $n$ of those error terms will still give you a small error.

Comment: So you are asking for a universal technique for summing, that obviously does not exist, or for the fundamental theorem of calculus? The FTC is crucial exactly because we do not have a universal summation technique.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, slow down.  It wasn't obvious to me.  I asked the question because I was not aware whether this technique existed or not.  If one could produce one, you would essentially *prove* the FTC.